# Load external image inside flash movie clip

Tags: flash, image, location, movie, clip

I have a flash movie clip and need to load an external image inside the clip that reference to an external URL.. like www.myimage.com/image.jpg i did something with XML but the image persist on every clip because it loads from actionscript using the x and y cords.

Help needed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
movieclipname.loadMovie("www.myimage.com/image.jpg");
```

I hope this will solve your problem